# What symbol means "or?"

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say I have

$$x=a\qquad\qquad\implies\qquad\qquad y\neq a~~,$$

and

$$x\neq a\qquad\qquad\implies\qquad\qquad y= a~~.$$

What is the symbol for writing the equivalent statement

$$x=a\qquad\qquad\text{"or"}\qquad\qquad y=a~~?$$

Comment: $(x=a )\vee (y =a)$.

Comment: turning your written maths into a stream of symbols might seem like a noble goal, but in fact its much more appealing to the reader if you use words imo.

Comment: Per Wikipedia, you have a choice of (x=a ) ⊕ (y =a) or (x=a ) ⊻ (y =a), neither of which will be familiar to 99% of your readers.

Comment: @xbh:  that is inclusive or, but OP wants exclusive or.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, i did not notice this.

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective), you may write $\not\leftrightarrow$, but this might not be clear enough. Natural language seems a better choice.

Comment: Let me concur and say that the teaching we get in school suggests to us that writing is “more mathematical” if it maximizes the number of symbols we use, minimizing the number of words. In fact, just the reverse is usually true. You may be surprised to look at a page of advanced mathematics, and see how few symbols there are.

Answer (score 0):

To write $(P\land \neg Q)\lor (Q\land \neg P)$ you could write $P\iff \neg Q.$

In mathematics there does not seem to be a widely-recognized single symbol for the "exclusive OR".